# Get key from the document object in mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner in node and mongodb. I am trying to log a value from an object returned from a query using mongoose. I can get the value if I run it within a loop but I am trying to get the value without using loop.

Here is my code

```
That.find({$and: [{"userId" : {"$ne" : ""}},{"userId" : {"$exists" : true}}]}).sort({"_id" : -1}).limit(1).select("userId").exec(function(err, doc)
            {
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log('User ID ERROR-');
                    callback({error:err,message:"Error getting max user ID"});
                }else {
                    console.log('User ID-');
                    console.log(doc);
                    console.log(typeof(doc));
                    doc.forEach(function(eachdoc) {
                        console.log(eachdoc.userId);
                    });
                    process.exit();
                }
            });
```

Instead of doing

```
doc.forEach(function(eachdoc) {
    console.log(eachdoc.userId);
});
```

why it is `undefined` if I do `console.log(doc.userId);`

Also is there any way to get rid of `_id` from the result.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`{_id :0}`** after query object in find function to remove `_id` from the `result. doc` is an array you can't access value directly either you have to use loop or `doc[0].userId`.

```
That.find({
    $and: [{
        "userId": {
            "$ne": ""
        }
    }, {
        "userId": {
            "$exists": true
        }
    }]
}, {
    _id: 0
}).sort({
    "_id": -1
}).limit(1).select("userId")
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering first question, you can use

```
console.log(doc[0].userId);
```

instead of

```
doc.forEach(function(eachdoc) {
    console.log(eachdoc.userId);
});
```

For the second question please refer [How to prevent MongoDB from returning the object ID when finding a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121145/how-to-prevent-mongodb-from-returning-the-object-id-when-finding-a-document)

Comment: Thanks for your help.