# Get Object(s) from MongoDB wihtout _id in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My aim is to render values of objects in a list. For that i want tou exclude the _id from the objects i get from the DB.
I get the collection with these functions:

```
function getCollection(collectionName) {
  if (db === null) {
    throw new Error("Database is not initialized. Call initDB first");
  }
  return db.collection(collectionName);
}
```

This is, how i try to exclude the _id:

```
const { getCollection } = require("./database");

function getAttendeeCollection() {
  return getCollection("attendees").find({}, { _id: 0 });
}
```

Thats how i found it on the documentation page from MongoDB ([Link](http://const%20%7B%20getCollection%20%7D%20=%20require(%22./database%22);%20%20function%20getAttendeeCollection()%20%7B%20%20%20return%20getCollection(%22attendees%22).find(%7B%7D,%20%7B%20_id:%200%20%7D);%20%7D)) and in this question on stackoverflow ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121145/how-to-prevent-mongodb-from-returning-the-object-id-when-finding-a-document))

I'm obviously doing something wrong, because it doesnt work in my case. Thats how the objects look like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e2efb0e06c1c35b619f6a9f",
        "name": "Test",
        "firstName": "Vorname",
        "address": "Musterstraße",
        "location": "Musterort, 12345",
        "email": "test@mail.de",
        "phone": "12345677898",
        "highschool": "test",
        "gender": "test",
        "nutrition": "test",
        "else": "test"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e2efbc51c9d44000092fc4e",
        "name": "Test",
        "firstName": "Vorname",
        "address": "Musterstraße",
        "location": "Musterort, 12345",
        "email": "test@mail.de",
        "phone": "12345677898",
        "highschool": "test",
        "gender": "test",
        "nutrition": "test",
        "else": "test"
    }, ...
]
```

Maybe somebody has a hint for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
`getCollection("attendees").find().select('-_id')` leads to `TypeError: collection.find(...).select is not a function`

Comment: You're looking at the shell documentation. Use the [node.js driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find) instead.

Comment: Oh yes man! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If my memories are ok try something like that :

```
getCollection("attendees").find().select('-_id')
```